# Get DevExtreme DropDownBox Selected Values

Tags: asp.net-core, devexpress, devextreme

I use multi select DevExtreme DropdownBox in View and fill it from model
but I can't get selected values in controller on Post method
how I can read selected values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a `@Html.HiddenField` then filled the hiddenfield value in below js function:

```
    function getSelectedItemsKeys(items) {
    var result = [];
    items.forEach(function (item) {
        if (item.selected) {
            result.push(item.key);
        }
        if (item.items.length) {
            result = result.concat(getSelectedItemsKeys(item.items));
        }
    });
    $("#myHF").val(result);
    return result;
}
```

then send hidden field to controller by view model.